# Django encrypted-filefield

Tags: django, encryption, view

I currently try to figure out how to implement the following:
https://github.com/danielquinn/django-encrypted-filefield
I only want to transparently encrypt my uploaded Data for later use on e.g. S3

First Problem is that I'm not able to get

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import AuthMixin
```

imported. I get the following exception:

> from django.contrib.auth.mixins import AuthMixin
>     ImportError: cannot import name 'AuthMixin'

I'm simply not able to find it. At what package is it located?

and second is that I have no idea how to implement the view if I only want encrypt and decrypt the file on the fly.
Any suggestions?

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from smartfields import fields
from smartfields.dependencies import FileDependency
from smartfields.processors import ImageProcessor
from django_encrypted_filefield.fields import EncryptedFileField

#Post Model
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    postattachment = EncryptedFileField(upload_to='postattachment/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
    postcover = fields.ImageField(upload_to='postcover/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True, dependencies=[
        FileDependency(processor=ImageProcessor(
            format='JPEG', scale={'max_width': 300, 'max_height': 300}))
    ])
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'quickblog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That mixin is not present in the django mixins. Maybe, the demo refers to a class extending any of the [mixins](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/mixins.py) you can find in django.

Having a look at the django sources, try with the class:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import AccessMixin
```

In the view, try to show the encoded file, it must be stored already encrypted.

Comment: Hey :D thx for the hint. "AccessMixin" seems to work but how to implement the view, i have no idea. This is currently my first project.